# Gradle subproject dependencyManagement like in Maven

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

`Maven` has a feature where dependencies versions management may be centralized in the root/parent project, and all child modules/sub-projects only point dependency name, when the version/scope/whatever are inherited from the parent.

[Maven Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

Does `gradle` have some standard approach for this? I found a couple of workarounds, like [Sprint Better Dependency Management for Gradle](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/23/better-dependency-management-for-gradle) and [How to Centralize Support Libraries](http://gmariotti.blogspot.de/2015/07/how-to-centralize-support-libraries.html), but i'm really curious if `gradle` has some built-in solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from gradle 5 there are:

- [Importing version recommendations from a Maven BOM](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import)
- [Fine-grained transitive dependency management](https://gradle.org/whats-new/gradle-5/#fine-grained-transitive-dependency-management)